# Hilt is converting a public field to private and failing to inject

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to learn Hilt and am getting the error "Dagger does not support injection into private fields". But the field in question isn't private in the original Kotlin. It's only private when it's converted to Java. Why is this? How can I correct it?

Original Kotlin file:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.example.vennwithnav.databinding.FragmentLoginBinding
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import javax.inject.Inject

@AndroidEntryPoint
class LoginFragment : Fragment() {
    @Inject public var profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel? = null
    private var binding: FragmentLoginBinding? = null
```

Java file after conversion (accessed via the error):

```
package com.example.vennwithnav.ui.profile;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import com.example.vennwithnav.databinding.FragmentLoginBinding;
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 4, 1}, bv = {1, 0, 3}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u0000:\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0005\n\u0002\u0010\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\b\u0007\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0005\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002J\u0006\u0010\u000b\u001a\u00020\fJ&\u0010\r\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010\u000e2\u0006\u0010\u000f\u001a\u00020\u00102\b\u0010\u0011\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010\u00122\b\u0010\u0013\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010\u0014H\u0016J\b\u0010\u0015\u001a\u00020\fH\u0016R\u0010\u0010\u0003\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010\u0004X\u0082\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u0002\n\u0000R\u001a\u0010\u0005\u001a\u00020\u0006X\u0086\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\u0007\u0010\b\"\u0004\b\t\u0010\n\u00a8\u0006\u0016"}, d2 = {"Lcom/example/vennwithnav/ui/profile/LoginFragment;", "Landroidx/fragment/app/Fragment;", "()V", "binding", "Lcom/example/vennwithnav/databinding/FragmentLoginBinding;", "profileViewModel", "Lcom/example/vennwithnav/ui/profile/ProfileViewModel;", "getProfileViewModel", "()Lcom/example/vennwithnav/ui/profile/ProfileViewModel;", "setProfileViewModel", "(Lcom/example/vennwithnav/ui/profile/ProfileViewModel;)V", "login", "", "onCreateView", "Landroid/view/View;", "inflater", "Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;", "container", "Landroid/view/ViewGroup;", "savedInstanceState", "Landroid/os/Bundle;", "onDestroyView", "app_debug"})
@dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint()
public final class LoginFragment extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment {
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    private com.example.vennwithnav.ui.profile.ProfileViewModel profileViewModel; // this line is causing the error
    private com.example.vennwithnav.databinding.FragmentLoginBinding binding;
    
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public final com.example.vennwithnav.ui.profile.ProfileViewModel getProfileViewModel() {
        return null;
    }
    
    public final void setProfileViewModel(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    com.example.vennwithnav.ui.profile.ProfileViewModel p0) {
    }
```

Comment: you should use `lateinit`: `lateinit var profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more google search found the answer. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#instance-fields

Adding @JvmField in front of var fixed the problem.

```
@Inject @JvmField var profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel? = null
```

per IR42, this works too, and is the used in the developer.android.com tutorials, so it's probably better.

```
@Inject lateinit var profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel
```